NpmErrorInvalidVersion 5_11_0
npm error Invalid Version: ^5.11.0
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\sathi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-08-04T20_15_12_001Z-debug-0.log
what ever i update still showing this error .
i need a solution to run the application
